# rich.Prompt to retrieve two numbers or a letter

Tags: python, input, rich

I have a coding issue I would like to share with you.

In my python code, I need some user inputs, in particular I need him to type in either a pair of float values or a specific letter from a list to execute a command.

Something like:

> Enter the required values OR Q to Exit:

I have coded everything using a while loop and the basic input followed by a series of checks on the input, but instead of my dodgy code, hard to maintain, I would like to use the rich.prompt to get a easier and nicer result.

I have seen that with rich.Prompt you can get a string (also among a choices list), an integer or a float. But I cannot see anyway how to mix these things.

Do you have any suggestion?

Thanks in advance,
toto

Comment: Let's see the code you're having trouble with

Comment: Please add more details showing what you've tried by posting current code, showing what it currently does, then what you expect or would like it to be doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try reading the source? [rich/prompt/prompt.py](https://github.com/Textualize/rich/blob/720800e6930d85ad027b1e9bd0cbb96b5e994ce3/rich/prompt.py#L310)

When there isn't very good documentation, go to the source and imitate - by looking at what I linked, I came up with this:

```
from typing import Union
from rich.prompt import PromptBase


RESPONSE_TYPE = Union[tuple[int, int], str]


class TwoIntsOrString(PromptBase[RESPONSE_TYPE]):
    response_type = RESPONSE_TYPE
    validate_error_message = "Please enter two integers or a string."

    def process_response(self, value: str) -> RESPONSE_TYPE:
        try:
            return tuple(int(x) for x in value.split()[:2])
        except ValueError:
            return value


if __name__ == "__main__":
    prompt = TwoIntsOrString("Enter two integers or a string: ")
    response = prompt.ask()
    print(f"Response: {response!r}")
```